# jQuery Accordion & jQuery Tooltip not working together

Tags: jquery, widget, tooltip, accordion

UPDATE: i worked with the code some more and got it to work. thanks for your comments.

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so please bear with me. I'm having some problems making my accordion and tooltips play nicely together.

I created my accordion first, using the Accordion Widget from the jQuery UI site. The accordion sections each contain a table with a form where there are text labels accompanied by a small image that is supposed to spawn a tooltip when hovered over.

I created the tooltips separately using this Tooltipster plugin (http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/). I used this plugin because I couldn't figure out how to use the jQuery UI site Tooltip widget to format the tooltips the way I wanted to (the tooltips contain images as well as HTML and CSS formatted text and links).

The tooltips only work when I pull out one of the tables from one of the accordion sections and place it on a page without the accordion code contained in it. When they're combined the accordion still works but the tooltips don't display.

Any ideas why this may be happening? Any tips on how to fix would be greatly appreciated. If any more information is needed, I'd be glad to provide it.

Thanks

Comment: You mean to say the tooltip works on the page but not in the accordion?

Comment: it would be fine to debug if you share some code or make a JS Fiddle and share.

Comment: The tooltips don't work when the images that a user hovers over to spawn the tips are contained inside the accordion. They work fine on their own.

Comment: I tried to create a JSFiddle but I'm not sure it's going to work because my page with both the accordion and tips contain so many external links to CSS, JS, etc. (this may be the source of my problem). Plus, I've never used it before.